# Folding body of functions in python with vim

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

For instance, if I have this function:

```
def foo():

    a = 5
    print a
    ...
```

If I fold it, I get this:

```
def foo():

+-- 123 lines: a = 5 ---------------------------------------------
```

but what I would really like would be something like this:

```
def foo():
+-- 124 lines: ---------------------------------------------
```

Using [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) plugin, I have `let g:pymode = 1` and `let g:pymode_folding = 1` in my `.vimrc`. Is this possible or not? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using pymode and fortunately I do not have your issue. Here is my settings in .vimrc. Hope it works for you.

```
let g:pymode_rope = 1
let g:pymode_doc = 1 "Documentation
let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'
let g:pymode_lint = 1 "Linting
let g:pymode_lint_checker = "pyflakes,pep8"
let g:pymode_lint_write = 1 "Auto check on save
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1 "Support virtualenv
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1 " Enable breakpoints plugin
let g:pymode_breakpoint_bind = '<leader>b'
let g:pymode_syntax = 1 "syntax highlightin
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_folding = 1 "0:Don't autofold code 1:enable python folding
```